# SQL, From TimeStamp to relative time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

For this SQL,

```
SELECT CID, Time, Val 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE CID = 8
```

I get the following data,

```
CID, Time, Val
8,2016-10-19 13:49:06.217,7.036
8,2016-10-19 13:49:15.237,6.547
8,2016-10-19 13:49:46.063,6.292
8,2016-10-19 13:49:57.387,5.998
```

I want each of `Time` value minus the starting time, which can be calculated by

```
SELECT MIN(Time) StartTime
FROM MyTable 
WHERE CID = 8
```

I know that I can define a T-SQL variable to do that, However, is it possible to do the task, getting the relative time instead of absolute time for each record, in one SQL?

Comment: JOIN with sub-query that calculates your minimum.

Comment: @PM77-1, that's where I'm having trouble doing and wanted to know, JOINing with sub-query. Can you show me how please? ... Two hours past, I'm marking vkp's reply as the answer for now, yet I'm still hoping you can come up with the sub-query solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `min()` window function to get the minimum time for each id and use it for subtraction.

```
select cid,time,val, 
datediff(millisecond,min(time) over(partition by cid),time) as diff
from mytable
```

Change the difference interval (`millisecond` shown) per your requirement. There can be an overflow if the difference is too big.